# Fan wiring no switch, only using humidity sensor for control

Tags: wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan

Putting in an exhaust fan for a bathroom that did not have one previously. Purchased one that has a humidity sensor and was looking to use that for the sole means of control (dont trust the kids to turn it on and off when they shower).

The fan has black & white to one connector for fan itself, and a black, white and brown from the connector labeled for humidity control. I did not plan on using any switch, just a direct hard wire to the unit.

Would I only wire the humidity sensors wires? Black & Brown to the hot, and white to white? Not certain if I need to use the other two at all or not, assuming a hard wire to them without a switch would just run the fan constantly. The instructions can be seen [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/918BlzdBkmL.pdf), they are for 1 or 2 switches though.

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel? We may have to go to a locking device on the breaker here, considering 422.35 requires disconnects to be indicating, which is something locking toggle switches don't provide.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to add the switches as the instructions say to do. All warranties as well as any UL listings will be voided if not installed according to the directions. From a practical sense, you need a easy means to shut off the fan for cleaning and maintenance. It appears that only the brown wire needs to be connected to hot to do what you want but there's not a diagram of the sensor. Again, this is not recommended, follow the directions.